# I want to go to a page by clicking a button by my own define Route in laravel-8

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-8

I have created a route called product_link. I can login to my website after login it's taken me to my index.blade.php. I want a button on index.blade.php which will take me to my product_link after clicking the button.
My created Route is

```
Route::get('products_link',[ProductController::class,'indextwo']);
```

I want something like this

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Go to Product Link </button>
</div>
```

Comment: where you've added the `<a>` tag in your code?

Comment: `<a>` or `<a href="#"></a>`

Comment: May Allah gives you wonderful gifts Thank you so much it's worked :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to redirect a user to products page you need to add a `<a>` in your code. Here's a working code for you:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
   <a href="{{ route('product-page')}} class="btn btn-primary">Go to Product Link </a>
</div>
```

and in your routes you can do this:

```
Route::get('products_link',[ProductController::class,'indextwo'])->name('product-page');
```

Comment: Mark it as an answer then